# What does 'Alias' in Virtualhost permanently modify?

Tags: apache2, alias, virtualhost, apache2.4

I added an 'Alias line' to my Virtualhost config `apache2/sites-available/domain1.conf` like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    ServerName www.domain1.tld
    DocumentRoot /www/directory1

    Alias /domain2 /www/directory2    #Alias line
</VirtualHost>
```

I later removed it, and restarted Apache2, but the server remembers the Alias line. I now have another virtualhost conf file where `www.domain2.tld` is pointed to `/www/directory2`, but when I go to `www.domain2.tld`, the address bar changes to `www.domain1.tld/domain2` and the browser displays an 'error' page.

Apparently some type of 'hosts' file has been permanently modified by the Alias command.

How do I undo this?

(In case it matters, all this was in the service of a PrestaShop installation.)

Comment: The Alias directive shouldn't cause any kind of redirects. Haven't used it personally, but maybe Prestashop has some kind of "base url" configuration, where `www.domain1.tld/domain2` is set? And maybe that is causing the redirect.

Comment: @Dan From my investigations it turns out that Prestashop stores the original URL in the mySQL database, and that causes the redirect. Would you have any thoughts on how Apache finds this URL in the mySQL database? I didn't think Apache has the ability to traverse a databse like that.

Comment: I meant to say that, Apache is most likely not doing doing any redirects by itself. And Apache is not traversing the MySQL DB, Prestashop is.